# DataReader error when i us it in the second time

Tags: c#, datareader

```
var filterConditions = new[] {
       CreateSqlFilter("CIVILIDD", ID_No, selectCommand, false),


};

        string filterCondition = filterConditions.Any(a => a != null) ? filterConditions.Where(a => a != null).Aggregate((filter1, filter2) => String.Format("{0} AND {1}", filter1, filter2)) : (string)null;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my"].ConnectionString))
        {
            selectCommand.Connection = connection;
            selectCommand.CommandText = filterCondition == null ? "SELECT * FROM _4" : "SELECT * FROM _4 WHERE " + filterCondition;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataSource);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dataSource;

            using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [_4] WHERE CIVILIDD = @id", mycon))
            {

                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID_No.Text);

                SqlDataReader dr = command2.ExecuteReader();





                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    txtname1.Text = (dr["name1"].ToString());
                    txtname2.Text = (dr["name2"].ToString());
                    Governorate.Text = (dr["Governorate"].ToString());
                    City.Text = (dr["City"].ToString());
                    Block.Text = (dr["Block"].ToString());
                    Street.Text = (dr["Street"].ToString());
                    Avenue.Text = (dr["Avenue"].ToString());
                    House.Text = (dr["House"].ToString());
                    Floor.Text = (dr["Floor"].ToString());
                    flat.Text = (dr["flat"].ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

i use this code to filter my database and i get that error when i run it in the first time it work good in the second time i get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.'
>
> in this line SqlDataReader dr = command2.ExecuteReader();

Comment: It won't compile, your **SqlDataReader dr** is defined twice.

Comment: @PiotrWojsa do you mean `  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);` and `SqlDataReader dr = command2.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: No, I mean **SqlDataReader dr** right before **while** loop.

Comment: Important point: `"select * from _4 where  CIVILIDD = '" + ID_No.Text.Trim() + "'"` is **incredibly** dangerous; anyone can take over (or destroy) your entire database just using the inputbox; never ever concatenate user input into SQL - use parameters, like you did with `@id` (and `filterConditions` scares be beyond all sensibility)

Comment: @MarcGravell i do it still gave me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to close the datareadre after you use it.

This is how your code should look like when you are not using `Using()`

Se the comment to understand

```js
var filterConditions = new[] {
       CreateSqlFilter("CIVILIDD", ID_No, selectCommand, false),


};

        string filterCondition = filterConditions.Any(a => a != null) ? filterConditions.Where(a => a != null).Aggregate((filter1, filter2) => String.Format("{0} AND {1}", filter1, filter2)) : (string)null;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my"].ConnectionString))
        {
            selectCommand.Connection = connection;
            selectCommand.CommandText = filterCondition == null ? "SELECT * FROM _4" : "SELECT * FROM _4 WHERE " + filterCondition;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataSource);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dataSource;

            using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [_4] WHERE CIVILIDD = @id", mycon))
            {

                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID_No.Text);

                SqlDataReader dr = command2.ExecuteReader();





                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    txtname1.Text = (dr["name1"].ToString());
                    txtname2.Text = (dr["name2"].ToString());
                    Governorate.Text = (dr["Governorate"].ToString());
                    City.Text = (dr["City"].ToString());
                    Block.Text = (dr["Block"].ToString());
                    Street.Text = (dr["Street"].ToString());
                    Avenue.Text = (dr["Avenue"].ToString());
                    House.Text = (dr["House"].ToString());
                    Floor.Text = (dr["Floor"].ToString());
                    flat.Text = (dr["flat"].ToString());
                }
                 // Close and Dispose the datareader
                 dr.Close();
                 dr.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose the first datareader that the adapter creates. The using statement will take care of the disposal of resources out of the box.

You can use associate a data reader with one command only (just as the error states). Create 2 using statements and prepare 2 datareaders. This can be in the same using( connection ) because a connection can be used for multiple commands, but you have to have separate datareaders for each command.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", c))
{
}

using( ..command2.. )
{
 SqlDataReader dr = command2.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Read more about there [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)

Comment: how can i do it in the first command it is already done in the second command

Comment: see in the edit my friend. you can also check this link: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter